# How to disable and check a checkbox based on searching through an array of values in an array in my .ts file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, html-select

I have this select with check boxes. I want to disable AND check the ones that exist in a string array.
How would I add both the `disabled` and `checked` attribute if value exists in an array I have in my angular .ts file.

> this.claimNames = any[];

```html
<div class="row container">
  <div *ngFor="let reno of renoList" class="form-group form-check col-md-3">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" disabled checked>
    <label class="form-check-label">{{reno}}</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show `renoList` and `claimNames `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wicfkm?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

**.html**

```
<div class="row container">
    <div *ngFor="let reno of renoList" class="form-group form-check col-md-3">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" [disabled]="claimNames.includes(reno)" [checked]="claimNames.includes(reno)">
        <label class="form-check-label">{{reno}}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**.ts**

```
renoList:any[] = ["A", "B", "C"];

claimNames:any[] = ["A"]
```

Comment: yup! this works. thanks! Just a little new to Angular and directives

Comment: just curious, do you know if there is a way to set both with one call instead of two?

Comment: @user1186050 Check the second way in the demo.